# Who is considering marriage here?

Tags: meaning

This is from a manga, if that matters. It's written on the bottom of the last page of the story, so there is no further info on what happened.

> 現在私は家を出て一人暮らし
>
> そして由利{ゆり}姉とは今でも続いており
>
> 本気で結婚を考えています
>
> I left that home and currently live alone. And "our thing" with Yuri-nee still continues. (I am/We are) seriously considering marriage.

So yeah, who is actually considering it? I'm not sure if a definite answer is possible, but perhaps one of the options seems more likely at least? I feel like it's "I am", but maybe in that case he should be considering プロポーズ since it's not clear how Yuri will answer? Or am I overthinking it?

Comment: The second 句点 should be 読点, I think?　i.e. "... 続いており、本気で ..."

Comment: Oh, punctuation is entirely mine by the way, on the manga page there are no commas or periods at all, just three phrases with some space between them. Maybe a comma would be better...

Comment: You can reproduce it the way it was originally written, maybe with the three phrases on separate lines if you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- 現在**私は**家を出て一人暮らし - Now / as for me / have left home / live alone
- **そして**由利姉とは今でも続いて**おり**  - also /as for with Yuri / continuing
- 本気で結婚を**考えています**  - seriously / thinking about marriage

「私」is the person considering marriage.
You can see that the topic starts out as 私は、and the rest of the language that follows until 結婚を考えています is extending that topic.

Comment: Nice answer!  In more detail, the key word being extending. There are two "layered" はs, the second submissive to the first. This is common in cases of には and とは parallel particles.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you think there is pretty much no ambiguity?

Comment: Yeah, I think it's pretty clear